# HTML CSS Float Label Pattern - Handling Optional Fields

Tags: css, html

I am exploring Float Label pattern for web page using HTML and CSS.
The code was referred from *http://codepen.io/boast/pen/pLjld*

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title required" />
```

The problem is "required" property is must to have Float Label effect here. Wanted to understand how can we achieve the Float Label effect for Optional Input Fields?

Comment: What do you want water mark like Price inside text box

Comment: you can see the demo here to understand requirement http://dribbble.com/shots/1254439--GIF-Float-Label-Form-Interaction

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class in conjunction with `:focus` and `+` adjacent selector:

https://github.com/tonystar/float-label-css

This method works in ANY browser (all non-supporting browsers will automatically fall back to the static layout w/o animation).

See demo below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tonystar/float-label-css/v1.0.0/dist/float-label.min.css"/>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Sign up</legend>

  <div class="form-group has-float-label">
    <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" placeholder="First Last"/>
    <label for="first">Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-float-label">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="email@example.com"/>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-float-label">
    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
  </div>
  
  <br/>

  <button>Sign up</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional pseudo class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:optional

Look at this sample below
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdaHk

Comment: thx, yes Optional works like this but then you lose the floating animation effect and also the place holder and label show redundant information. We need same effect as Required attribute achieves for Optional fields

Answer (score -1):

[Click here to view Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6P23j/4/)

### Html

```
<form id="formID" action="demo_form.asp">
    <label for="fname" id="lblfname" >First name </label><br> 
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
  <label for="lname" id="lbllname" >Last name </label><br>      
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### Css

```
label{
visibility:hidden;
   z-index:1; 
    font-size:10px;
}
```

### Jquery

```
$('#fname').focus(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = offset.left;
    var yPos = offset.top;
    alert(xPos);
    alert(yPos);
    var myid = this.id;
    var res = $('label[for=' + myid + ']').attr('id');
    var offset1 = $("#" + res + "").offset();
    offset1
    var xxPos = offset1.left;
    var yyPos = offset1.top;
    alert(xxPos);
    alert(yyPos);
   $("#"+ res).css({ visibility: "visible"});
$("#"+ res).css({
    top: xPos + 17,
    left: yPos + 80,
    position: 'absolute'
});
alert(res);
});
$('#lname').focus(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = offset.left;
    var yPos = offset.top;
  //  alert(xPos);uncomment and run this to get top
 //   alert(yPos);uncomment and run this to get left
    var myid = this.id;
    var res = $('label[for=' + myid + ']').attr('id');
    var offset1 = $("#" + res + "").offset();
    offset1
    var xxPos = offset1.left;
    var yyPos = offset1.top;
  //   alert(xxPos);uncomment and run this to get top
 //    alert(yyPos);uncomment and run this to get top

   $("#"+ res).css({ visibility: "visible"});
$("#"+ res).css({
    top: xPos + 65,
    left: yPos +35,
    position: 'absolute'
});
alert(res);
});

$("input").blur(function(){
$('#formID').find('label').each(function(){
  $(this).css({ visibility: "hidden"});;
});
});
```